# Sliced column of Pandas dataframe keep mentioning original column name in new objects created from the column

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I sliced from a pandas dataframe to create object label. The name of the column in the original dataframe was `y`.

Now when I take sum of `label` and assign it to `m`, while printing it keeps showing `y`. Why is it doing so and what is it trying to mean by writing `y   50.0`?

```
>>> type(label)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> label.head(2)
     y
0  1.0
1  1.0
>>> m = label.sum()
>>> m
y    50.0
dtype: float64
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `label` DataFrame contains only 1 column named `y` with 50 rows of `1.0`, so it returned `sum of y`. In your code the name became the index name (a sum of a single column) since all index in DataFrame *needs* a name, you can rename that using `m.index = <insert a name or int here>`, but `m.index = None` will raise `TypeError` exception.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(50), columns=['y'])
>>> df.head(2)
     y
0  1.0
1  1.0
>>> df
      y
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
... # reducted
48  1.0
49  1.0
>>> df.sum()
y    50.0
dtype: float64

>>> m = df.sum()
>>> m
y    50.0
dtype: float64
>>> m.index
Index(['y'], dtype='object')
>>> m.index = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, None was passed
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be expecting `m` as `float`.
No, `m` is a `Series`.

```
>>> type(m) # to know type of `m`
pandas.core.series.Series

>>> m.dtype # to know type of data contained in `m`
dtype('float64')
```

Doing `DataFrame.sum()` will generally return a Series (or Dataframe in some cases). See
[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).

That's why when you printed `m` you didn't get only the number `50.0`, rather you got the Series `m` with `y` as the index, and `50.0` as the value.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `label['y'].sum()`

`label` is a `pd.DataFrame` object, and [`pd.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) is different to `pd.Series.sum`. "Summing a dataframe" with no arguments means summing over all indices for *each column*. For this, if you want to be explicit, you could use `axis=0`, but this is not required:

```
sums_by_col = label.sum(axis=0)
```

But what you really want is [`pd.Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
sum_of_series = label['y'].sum()
```